# Find elements in Mat, Opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I came across this:

```
 cv::Mat Mat_out;
 cv::Mat Mat2(openFingerCentroids.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(2)); imshow("Mat2", Mat2);
 cv::Mat Mat3(openFingerCentroids.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(3)); imshow("Mat3", Mat3);
 cv::bitwise_and(Mat2, Mat3, Mat_out); imshow("Mat_out", Mat_out);
```

Why does `Mat_out` contain all 2? Bit-wise operation of a matrix of all 2s and 3s should give me 0, right? Since 2 is not equal to 3?

Anyway, this is the simple thing I tried to implement: (like [`find` function of MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html))

```
Mat_A = {1, 1, 0, 9, 0, 5;
         5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0;
         1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Output expected, if I'm searching for all 5s:

```
Mat_out = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5;
           5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

How can I do this in OpenCV using C++??

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is openFingerCentroids, what are Mat2 and Mat3?

Comment: bitwise-and (`&`) is not the same as logical-and (`&&`)... bitwise-and does the ands per bit so `2 & 3 == 2`

Comment: you'll want `cv::compare(a, b, out, CMP_EQ)` [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html)

Comment: `openFingerCentroids` is a random matrix of 2D. The size doesn't matter, therefore I didn't mention it here.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x : If you post this as an Answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, `cv::Mat Out = Mat_A == 5;` works as well.